# UISwitch и жесты

Tags: ios, swift

Как можно переопредилить или добавить жест к switch? Нужно добавить PanGesture к UISwitch.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы с помощью этого жеста хотите сделать?

Comment: Есть switch на self.view нужно что бы с помощью pan жеста он перемещался по self.view. То есть двигался за пальцем. Зачем это нужно - особо в голову не берите. Сейчас при попытке добавить к нему любой жест, ни чего не происходит. Кроме стандартного жеста tap, то есть либо on либо off state switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, с которой вы столкнулись связана с тем, что обработчик UISwitch перехватывает жест и игнорирует ваш. Чтобы ознакомиться подробнее с этим [HitTest link](https://medium.com/yandex-maps-ios/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80-%D1%81-hittest-542653d51a8c).

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать.